# QFT: the origin of vacuum correlation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-entanglement, vacuum

My question is about the origin (or mechanism?) of vacuum correlation.

In quantum field theory in flat spacetime, a free scalar field has the following two-point correlation function at the same time $t=0$: 
$$
\langle 0|\phi(0,x) \phi(0,y)|0 \rangle 
\sim 
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{|x-y|^2},~~(|x-y|\ll m^{-1}) \\
e^{-m(x-y)},~~(|x-y|\gg m^{-1})
\end{cases}.
$$
This should look like this figure.
[image]

As it is clear from the above, the vacuum of free fields is correlated even for spacelike points. Also, it diverges as two points get closer.

My question is

(1) Why does the vacuum of the free scalar field have spacelike correlation? Physicists interpret this correlation as vacuum entanglement. But is this mean that entangled vacuum has to do with the past? To my knowledge, generating entanglement is like the figure below; one can generate an entangled pair at one spacetime point and then they propagate through spacetime, eventually they become spacelike entangled pair. So, for me, the spacelike correlation seems to come from the past.

[image]

(2) What does the divergent correlation in the limit $|x-y|\rightarrow 0$ mean?

Thanks.

Comment: Ultimately, the correlation of field variables stems from the kinetic term of the free scalar field $\partial_\mu\phi\partial^\mu\phi$.  The nonvanishing of spacelike separation shouldn't be a surprise to you -- a familiar case is the Coulomb field around the electron:  if you know the electron is stationary at $x$, you have a good idea for what the electric field looks like some distance from it with a spacelike separation.